# Codeigniter extending extended MY_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have strictly followed the [how-to article by Phil Sturgeon](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY), to extend the base controller. But I get still some errors.

My 3 classes:

```
// application/libraries/MY_Controller.php
class MY_Controller extends Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

// application/libraries/Public_Controller.php
class Public_Controller extends MY_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

    }    
}

// application/controllers/user.php
class User extends Public_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Class 'Public_Controller' not found in /srv/www/xxx/application/controllers/user.php on line 2

Curious is that the following snippet is working, if I directly extends from `MY_Controller`:

```
// application/controllers/user.php
class User extends MY_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

I have loaded the controllers via `__autoload()` or manually. The controllers are loaded succesfully.

CI-Version: 1.7.3

Comment: Are you loading MY_Controller.php before Public_Controller.php is loaded?

Comment: Could you post the __autoload function in config.php?

Comment: There are much better answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663045/creating-a-core-class-that-extends-another-core-class-codeigniter/22125436#22125436 even as if it's marked as a duplicated of this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to require the Public Controller in your MY_Controller

```
// application/libraries/MY_Controller.php
class MY_Controller extends Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

require(APPPATH.'libraries/Public_Controller.php');
```

You get the error because Public_Controller was never loaded. Doing this would allow you to extend from `Public_Controller`

I like what you are doing because I do that all the time.

You can do this also in your MY_Controller when you want to create an Admin_Controller

```
// application/libraries/MY_Controller.php
class MY_Controller extends Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

require(APPPATH.'libraries/Public_Controller.php'); // contains some logic applicable only to `public` controllers
require(APPPATH.'libraries/Admin_Controller.php'); // contains some logic applicable only to `admin` controllers
```

Comment: @Phil, he missed that part in your post :)

Comment: Oh. "I have loaded the controllers via __autoload() or manually." Who knows :)

Comment: To those want to use this snippet: Since version 2 `Controller` core class is changed to `CI_Controller`.

Comment: @Phil What about using hooks ? I have used this method, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22125436/567854

Answer (score 5):

You should place `Public_controller` in with `MY_Controller` inside MY_Controller.php

```
// application/libraries/MY_Controller.php
class MY_Controller extends Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Public_Controller extends MY_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

    }    
}
```

I use __construct everywhere and it works fine I recently wrote up [an article](http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/01/scalable-login-system-for-codeigniter-ion_auth) on how to do this in relation to wrapping your auth logic into your extended controllers.  It's about half way down when I start discussing constructing your controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved here: http://devcrap.net/pl/2011/09/04/codeigniter-dziedziczenie-z-my_controller-extends-my_controller/. In polish but code is good :]

Answer (score 1):

I had problem like this,After some search I found error was made myself,Because my controller class name was MY_Controller but file name was My_Controller[Case not matching].
Note:- In localhost I didnt have any error.

In extended controller I Use

```
class Home  extends MY_Controller{
   function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

even I got the error.

After changing my file name to  MY_Controller it started to work well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom controller class called **`MY_Controller`** it extends CI_Controller and it works fine. It is located at application/core and it has custom functions lo load views in my site.

I use an abstract class **`My_app_controller`** that extends `MY_Controller` for my_app specific behabior, I want every controller in my_app to extend this abstract class. (I use diferent apps in the site, so some apps will extend `My_app_controller` and other apps will extend `My_other_apps_controllers`)

But when I try to extend `My_app_controller` from any controller in my application, "**`Main_app_controller extends My_app_controller`**" generates a **Class 'My_app_controller' not found exception**.

I found two solutions:

1. use **include_once** in Main_app_controller.php file. 
   `include_once APPPATH.'controllers/path/to/My_app_controler.php';`
2. break the "one class per file" rule of code igniter and define my `My_app_controller` just in the same file `MY_Controller` is (under application/core).

Manual says:

> Use separate files for each class, unless the classes are closely
>   related

Well... they are.

Anyway, I prefered to use the include_once solution as I think it is better to have one file per class and My_app_controller is located under application/controllers/my_app folder. (so application/controllers/other_apps will exist)