# How can I get the __construct() in MY_Controller to run?

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor, extend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Codeigniter extending extended MY_Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609127/codeigniter-extending-extended-my-controller)

I have been fiddling with this problem for a while now, and am at the point of frustration.  I am extending the controller class with MY_Controller.

**Here are the details:**

- `__construct()` does not seem to be called.
- The file is located in application/core as it should be
- The file is named MY_Controller.php
- I have `MY_` set up as the prefix for extensions (I have other extensions which work fine)

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'TESTING!!!'; // This should print, followed by an ob_start() error
    }

}
```

I should get a page back that says `TESTING!!!` followed by an ob_start() error, but instead the page renders normally.

**I have tried** splitting up the constructor class and just calling a private function within MY_Controller, but that doesn't work.  I know the file is being called because if I purposefully create a php error within MY_Controller.php, the page will error out.  It seems to me that the `__construct()` is just not running.

Comment: `MY_Controller` should not live in application/core

Comment: Where should it live? I was under the impression that it should live there...

Comment: @Madbreaks I'm fairly certain that it should remain in application/core.  The file is being called, it's just the constructor function which is not running....

Comment: MY_Controller should be under application/controllers. What is the reason to keep it in application/core? Also what version of CI are you running?

Comment: @KaranAshar No.  Controllers go there, not an extended core class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703803/error-in-extending-codeigniter-controller

Comment: @Madbreaks This is not a duplicate of that question.  I have read that question and it is not similar.  Given your comments, I'm not even sure that you've read my question fully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you show an example of one your controllers under application/controllers? Pls note that the controllers under application/controller should extend MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller - I think this is what you missed.

For example, under your controller application/controller/test.php. it should look like this:

```
class Test extends MY_Controller {        
    public function index()
    {
         echo 'test';
    }
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a gem.  I was not extending MY_Controller on my page controllers.

Comment: Will accept in 2 mins - when it lets me.