# creating a core class that extends another core class codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

```
class Settings extends USER_Controller {...}

class USER_Controller extends MY_Controller {...}//limit access to user and define some params and functions that is user depended

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {...}//provide extra functionality accross all controllers
```

well if i try to create above 3 class's this will not work.

yet if i just use `settings extends MY_Controller` it will work fine.

so is there a way i can put a middle class between my controller and MY_Controller -the base controller that extends CI_Controller ?

Comment: How did you extend the core classes? did you use different files?

Comment: Even as marked as duplicated, the accepted solution here is by far better than all the other solutions proposed in the "original" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **@Minhaz Ahmed** said, the problem is loading the class. Codeigniter only loads the class with the subclass prefix as in,

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/CodeIgniter.php#L276

```
if (file_exists(APPPATH.'core/'.$CFG->config['subclass_prefix'].'Controller.php'))
{
    require APPPATH.'core/'.$CFG->config['subclass_prefix'].'Controller.php';
}
```

So after some diggings I have came with a solution using both **codeigniter hooks** and **`spl_​autoload_​register()`** for my project without hacking the CORE. Please follow the steps to achieve what's in **THE QUESTION**.

1. Enable hooks in the config file if it isn't already.
2. create a hook in application/config/hooks.php as below.

   `$hook['pre_system'] = array(
       'class'     => '',
       'function'  => 'autoload',
       'filename'  => 'autoload.php',
       'filepath'  => 'hooks',
       'params'    => ''
   );`
3. Create the **`autoload.php`** in **`application/hooks`** folder.
4. inside the **`autoload.php`** file,

   `function autoload()
   {
       spl_autoload_register(function($class)
       {
           if(strpos($class,'CI_') !== 0 && file_exists(APPPATH.'core/'.$class.EXT))
           {
               require_once APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT;
           }
       });
   }`

**That's it.**

**Note:** Here, I've used **`pre_system`** hook, not **`pre_controller`**, since codeigniter loads the base controller classes between **`pre_system`** and **`pre_controller`** hooks.

Hope this helps. If there are any issues with this please do comments.

Comment: nice code, thanks for sharing

Comment: Have you tried in CI 3.0.3? It's not working in CI 3.0.3

Comment: No man.. Sorry .. I am out of touch with CI.. Moved Laravel ;)

Answer (score 1):

Place the user_controller class file at the end of MY_Controller.php

MY_Controller.php in /application/core/

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {...}
class USER_Controller extends MY_Controller {...}
```

Now from your controller in your controllers folder, you can extend the controller from USER_Controller:

```
 class Settings extends USER_Controller {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

What did the best job for CI 2.1.4:
application/core

create for example:
- base_controller (base instructions, extending from ci_controller)
- admin_controller (extending from basecontroller and adds authentication instructions)


Then use them in: application/controllers:
for example:
class users extends admin_controller...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Phil's core solution, its simple and easy.

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

Comment: Whith Phil solution, you only can define one autoload. Check http://php.net//manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: You could extend all classes each other if you want another core class. So basicly on Object Oriented idea based on this?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is not about extending it, the problem is how your PHP file finds the classes when they're not directly included in your code via include/require. __autoload defines how to do it, but with spl_autoload_register you may define more than one function, in case it doesn't find it with autolad nor it's included

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the class the way you want but the problem is loading the class, you have to include your `USER_Controller` your `Settings` Class. Problem is not extend problem is including the file, so you have to find a way to include the second class.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php