# CodeIgniter - is it possible to create my own controller in any other name

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have created custom controller called "**MY_Controller.php**" in **Application/core**, and successfully invoked by inheriting through application controller.

```
//application/core
class MY_AdminController extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();            
    }
 }

//application/controllers
class User extends MY_AdminController {
    public function __construct(){
          parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

It works fine. I just changed my file name from "MY_Controller.php" to **MY_AdminController.php**, **and following same class name**, but it is throwing following error,

```
Fatal error: Class 'MY_AdminController' not found
```

As per the documentation, Whenever you create a class with the **MY_** prefix the CodeIgniter Loader class will load this after loading the core library, then why its throwing error...!!!

Answer (score 2):

Go to your config.php and change

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_'; to $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_Admin';
```

Comment: Thanks...Its working fine, How can I create multiple custom classes with different name? is that not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Patel,
the issue is that MY_ is the prefix to the original core files.

Controller, Model, View etc.

MY_ will be used to seek the name of the controller, for example, MY_controller searches for CI_controller.

You cannot load random names using the MY_prefix. you use MY_ to extend the already existing names.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the class name, you may have not changed the class name from `MY_Controller` to `MY_AdminController`

Comment: No I am following same class name which I have given to the file name

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom classes. But CI only loads the classes with the class prefix in the config file (e.g. **`MY_`**). So I explained how it works and created a workaround to load classes automatically. You can find it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22125436/567854.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include all the files that are in your core folder. Then write the following code in end of config.php file.Path to file is application/config/config.php

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
         @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT );
    }
}
```

By using this you can create multiple classes.

Comment: Better use hooks rather than including a function in file (**`config.php`**) which is meant to contain only configurations, not any functions. If you still want to use above method, better include this function in **`application/config/autoload.php`**, it will be more meaningful.